# MaterialDesignXamlToolkit wpf dialoghost buttons are disabled when opened

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, material-design, mahapps.metro

I am using the MaterialDesignThemes nuget package along with the Mahapps.Metro package

I have this DialogHost

```
<material:DialogHost Name="PopupAddCustom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsOpen="False" >
    <material:DialogHost.DialogContent>
        <StackPanel Margin="16" Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label Content="Add custom date" FontSize="16" />
            <DatePicker />
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Content="ACCEPT" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}" IsDefault="True" Margin="0,8,8,0" Command="material:DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand" CommandParameter="True" />
                <Button Content="CANCEL" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}" IsCancel="True" Margin="0,8,8,0" Command="material:DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand" CommandParameter="False" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </material:DialogHost.DialogContent>
</material:DialogHost>
```

That is being openend by this button

```
<Button MinWidth="120" Margin="10" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedAccentButton}" ToolTip="Add in a new custom date." Command="{x:Static material:DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand}" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=PopupAddCustom}"  >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=Foreground}">
            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource fa_plus}" />
            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        </Rectangle>
        <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Custom" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

However when this dialog gets opened the ACCEPT and CANCEL buttons are disabled. So to check if anything was wrong I manually opened this dialog from the my MainWindow constructor like this

```
this.Loaded += delegate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    this.PopupAddCustom.IsOpen = true;
};
```

When I open the dialog like this the button are in working order, am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was resolved by setting a command target for the buttons like this

```
 CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=PopupAddCustom}"
```

Answer (score 0):

To save someone elses time: I had dialog content specified as command parameter and specifying `CommandTarget` did not help me.

What helps in my case, is to **put `CommandParameter` before `Command`**.

You can achieve that by passing content as resource.

### Example:

#### Before:

```
<Button 
   ... 
   Command="{x:Static material:DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand}"
   >
   <Button.CommandParameter>
       <Grid>
         ** Dialog content **
       </Grid>
   </Button.CommandParameter>
   ** Button content **
</Button>
```

#### After:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <Grid x:Key="MyDialogContent">
    ** Dialog content **
  </Grid>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Button 
   ... 
   CommandParameter="{StaticResource MyDialogContent}"
   Command="{x:Static material:DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand}"
   >
   ** Button content **
</Button>
```

And dialoghost buttons were not disabled anymore.